# Chain jQuery .addClass and .removeClass multiple times with delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm working with animate.css from https://github.com/daneden/animate.css and it provides just much better animations than jQuery does. I would like to chain animations and element changes with delays to fade an element in and out and change it's contents.

The .queue method works for a single delay, but I need an efficient way to chain many .addClass, .removeClass and .html methods with a delay and the least possible syntax.

Does anybody know how to do this?

**Here's an example (doesn't work, but that's what it should be):**

```
$('div.text').delay(2000).addClass('animated fadeOutLeft').html('New content!').delay(2000).addClass('animated fadeInRight');
```

And that repeated many times with different content.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()`, delay doesn't work for addClass

Comment: setTimeout() seems to slow performance down. Is there way to do it with jQuery? Would you also mind providing an example in an answer (so I could mark it correct if it fits my needs etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) works with only those method with uses the [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) based execution like [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), so it doesn't work with [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

You can use a manual queue to fix it like

```
$('div.text').delay(2000).queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass('animated fadeOutLeft').html('New content!').delay(2000).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeInRight')
    }).dequeue()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jfuca7ds/)

Comment: Now how would I add another iteration of that? Hide it again, set new text, show it again?